# Why the % percentage sign is used in Python to call a library, such as Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, shared-libraries

In the following code, Why the % percentage sign is used in Python to call the Matplotlib library?
Does the % sign have this other operation assigned to it, other than arithmetic operations? Why the % sign is used here? What does it mean?

```
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10000)
y = np.exp(-x**2)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('exp(-x^2)')
plt.show()
```

I tried Google search but could not found much information.

Comment: It's not a python functionality, but an instruction to IPython, the code behind a Jupyter notebook. It is an example of a [magic function](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#magics-explained)

Comment: @JohanC Worth mentioning that it **only** has meaning in the context of Jupyter. In a "plain" Python environment, it will lead to a SyntaxError exception